# Brightness control not working on Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 laptop in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, laptop, brightness, ideapad

I have a Lenovo laptop I bought in summer 2020. Back then, I remember installing Ubuntu 20.04 onto it and the brightness control and the touchpad both not working. A few months went by and a few others posted that they had the same laptop and had the same problem, but no solution ever came up.

Fast forward to summer 2022, and I'm trying Linux again on it. I tried Fedora out of curiosity, and all hardware worked this time! :) But I missed the Ubuntu ecosystem. I tried Ubuntu 22.04. Now the touchpad works, unlike with Ubuntu 20.04 two years ago! :) But the brightness controls don't. When I hold the `Fn` key and then press the F keys that show the brightness up and brightness down icons, I see the GUI element with a bar going left (toward empty) and right (toward full), but the screen brightness stays the same. It seems to be running at either full brightness or close to that all the time.

My goal is for the brightness to increase and decrease when I adjust it via the `Fn` and brightness keys on my keyboard, when I'm booted into Ubuntu 22.04.

System details:

Model: IdeaPad Gaming 3 (15")
Processor: AMD® Ryzen™ 5 4600H Processor (3.00 GHz, up to 4.00 GHz Max Boost, 6 Cores, 12 Threads, 8 MB Cache)

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Output of `uname -r` (including because I've heard that kernels have to do with hardware support):

```
5.15.0-47-generic
```

Additional Drivers info:

[image: nvidia driver selected in Additional Drivers]

Comment: have you installed Nvidia drivers? I had the same issue and it was solved after installing them

Comment: Yes. There were a bunch in the list and I couldn't copy and paste from it, so I updated my question to include the info in a screenshot.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is an on-topic question about a supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way with my Lenovo IdeaPad with Intel-CPU and XUbuntu:

1. Create the following files as root and be carefully if you change the sudoers-file, use visudo for it.
2. Activate the possibility to execute commands in "rc.local".
3. Now you can go in the Keyboard-Settings and add keyboard-shorts with the commands /bin/helligkeit_plus, /bin/helligkeit_minus, /bin/helligkeit_standard and /bin/helligkeit_null.

| German | English |
| --- | --- |
| helligkeit_plus | brightness darker |
| helligkeit_minus | brightness brighter |
| helligkeit_standard | set the brightness to a standard-value (value here 400) |
| helligkeit_null | dark screen, backlight off |

In /etc/rc.local

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# /etc/rc.local: Local multi-user startup script.
#
# Helligkeitswert verstellbar machen:
chmod ugo+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
# Standardhelligkeitswert beim Starten einstellen:
echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
exit 0
```

In /etc/sudoers

```bash
%users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
%users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
%users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/helligkeit_minus
%users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/helligkeit_plus
%users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/helligkeit_standard
%users     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/helligkeit_null
```

In /bin/helligkeit_minus

```bash
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i aktuellehelligkeit
aktuellehelligkeit=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness)
#echo $aktuellehelligkeit
let aktuellehelligkeit=aktuellehelligkeit-10
echo $aktuellehelligkeit > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
unset aktuellehelligkeit
```

In /bin/helligkeit_plus

```bash
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i aktuellehelligkeit
aktuellehelligkeit=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness)
#echo $aktuellehelligkeit
let aktuellehelligkeit=aktuellehelligkeit+10
echo $aktuellehelligkeit > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
unset aktuellehelligkeit
```

In /bin/helligkeit_standard

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Standardhelligkeitswert beim Starten
echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

In /bin/helligkeit_null

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Standardhelligkeitswert beim Starten
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I think I could follow the instructions but it also goes mostly over my head. I'm confused about why one would need to do these steps. What are these files? Do they represent files that in a normal Ubuntu installation, would be pre-configured according to each person's hardware so that pressing function keys worked properly? I'm vaguely familiar with the `/etc/sudoers` file (it must have to do with `sudo`) but why are we editing it in order to get laptop brightness keys working?

Comment: Oh, I see that you have an AMD PC. So you have to use the path:"/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness". Replace "intel_backlight" with "acpi_video0".  In my laptop it was so, that the function in the system-core exist, but it was not useable over the graphical system. So I had to set it by hand. I only change the number in this one file, this is all. Th other steps make it possible to give you the right to change it. Before I did the entry in sudoers, I could not change the value by key, because I must enter the password every time.